# I get Access Forbidden (Error 403) when setting up new alias

Tags: xampp

I'm running windows 7 and recently installed XAMPP to build a dev environment. I'm not great with the server side of things so I'm having some problems setting up an alias for a project.

So far XAMPP is running and if I go to localhost I get the XAMPP welcome page. I created an "alias" folder in my "conf" folder of my apache install. In there I added dev.conf with the following content:

```
<Directory "C:\Users\my_user\My%20Documents\Aptana%20Studio%203%20Workspace\project">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>

Alias /dev "C:\Users\my_user\My%20Documents\Aptana%20Studio%203%20Workspace\project"
```

But then when I go to "localhost/dev" I get:

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either
>   read-protected or not readable by the server.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403

I tried googling and I found other similar questions on SO but I can't seem to figure it out. Some say that you have to tell it to have permissions but in my conf file I specified to allow it from 127.0.0.1. Maybe this is because my path has spaces in it (though some googling told me %20 work). I had managed to create one to a different folder and copy pasted the working one and changed the alias and path and it broke so it this tells me it probably has something to do with either.

I looked in my log folder and found the following line:

> [Tue Dec 13 14:59:20 2011] [error] [client ::1] client denied by
>   server configuration: C:/Users/my_user/My%20Documents

I'm not sure if it cuts because error messages can only be of a certain length but that's definitely not the path I added in the dev.conf file, I'm hoping this can make this a bit clearer for some because I am getting pretty frustrated and I'm not sure what to try anymore.

Comment: For anyone who might have missed this, as I did: You have to make sure there is no trailing slash on any of the paths. I had trailing slash in my alias like this: `Alias /aliasdir/ "D:/path/to/place"`. Everything else was correct, but that trailing slash was resulting in a 403.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally got it to work.

I'm not sure if the spaces in the path were breaking things but I changed the workspace of my Aptana installation to something without spaces.

Then I uninstalled XAMPP and reinstalled it because I was thinking maybe I made a typo somewhere without noticing and figured I should be working from scratch.

Turns out Windows 7 has a service somewhere that uses port 80 which blocks apache from starting (giving it the -1) error. So I changed the port it listens to port 8080, no more conflict.

Finally **I restarted my computer**, for some reason XAMPP doesn't like me messing with ini files and just restarting apache wasn't doing the trick.

Anyway, this has been the most frustrating day ever so I really hope my answer ends up helping someone out!

Comment: I would put my money on that "other service" being Skype. If you open Skype and go to `Tools > Options > Advanced > Connection` and then look for the checkbox which says _Use Port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections_.  Make sure that's unchecked. Restart Skype and then you should be able to run Apache on port 80 again.

Comment: @Adam: doesn't have to be Skype. I have a similar issue with Dropbox, and changing its required ports doesn't seem as easy as for Skype. But if you know how to do it, please answer corresponding question on SU: http://superuser.com/q/850749/373304

Comment: @gazillion I don't know if you do development in Visual Studio but IIS Express uses port 80 by default.

Answer (score 85):

I just found the same issue with Aliases on a Windows install of Xampp.

To solve the 403 error:

```
<Directory "C:/Your/Directory/With/No/Trailing/Slash">
   Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /dev "C:/Your/Directory/With/No/Trailing/Slash"
```

The default Xampp set up should be fine with just this. Some people have experienced issues with a deny placed on the root directory so flipping out the directory tag to:

```
<Directory "C:/Your/Directory/With/No/Trailing/Slash">
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Would help with this but the current version of Xampp (v1.8.1 at the time of writing) doesn't require it.

As for op's issue with port 80 Xampp includes a handy Netstat button to discover what's using your ports. Fire that off and fix the conflict, I imagine it could have been IIS but can't be sure.

Comment: Thanks to you and to `Require all granted` it works!

Comment: after that please test in incognito

Comment: where will I put this?

Answer (score 31):

I'm using XAMPP with Apache2.4, I had this same issue. I wanted to leave the default xampp/htdocs folder in place, be able to access it from locahost and have a Virtual Host to point to my dev area...

The full contents of my `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\http-vhosts.conf` file is below...

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#

##NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\nick\static"
    ServerName dev.middleweek.co.uk
    <Directory "C:\nick\static">
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I then updated my `C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file like this...

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1   dev.middleweek.co.uk
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Restart your machine for good measure, open the XAMPP Control Panel and start Apache.

Now open your custom domain in your browser, in the above example, it'll be http://dev.middleweek.co.uk

Hope that helps someone!

And if you want to be able to view directory listings under your new Virtual host, then edit your VirtualHost block in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\http-vhosts.conf` to include "Options Indexes" like this...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\nick\static"
    ServerName dev.middleweek.co.uk
    <Directory "C:\nick\static">
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Cheers,
Nick

Comment: +1 I've managed to overcome the "Access forbidden" error only after adding "Require all granted" line. More about that is written at `What does Apache's “Require all granted” really do?` http://serverfault.com/a/549559

Answer (score 23):

This question is old and although you managed to make it work but I feel it would be helpful if I make clear some of points you have raised here.

First about directory name having spaces. I have been playing with apache2 configuration files and I have discovered that, if the directory name has space then enclose it in double quotes and all problems disappear.
For example...

```
    NameVirtualHost     local.webapp.org
    <VirtualHost local.webapp.org:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        DocumentRoot "E:/Project/my php webapp"
        ServerName local.webapp.org
    </VirtualHost>
```

Note the way DocumentRoot line is written.

Second is about Access forbidden from xampp. I found that default xampp configuration (..path to xampp/apache/httpd.conf) has a section that looks like the following.

```
    <Directory>
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
```

Change it and make it look like below. Save the file restart apache from xampp and that solves the problem.

```
    <Directory>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
       AllowOverride none
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Comment: The last option (require all granted) worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

try this

> sudo chmod -R 0777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/testproject

Comment: This is a Windows environment.

Comment: This answer helped me even though it won't help the asker

Comment: Worked for me on a Mac (which is what I was looking for). Thanks!

Comment: Why is this getting up votes? This is a terrible way of fixing the problem because of the gaping security hole you just created.

Comment: Don't do this, this is a major security issue as you give write and execute rights to everyone!

Comment: Helped on Mac! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Apache 2.4 virtual hosts hack

1.In http.conf specify the ports , below “Listen”

```
Listen 80
Listen 4000
Listen 7000
Listen 9000
```

2. In  httpd-vhosts.conf

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
   DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Vikas/Documents/NetBeansProjects/slider_website_hitesh/public_html"  
   ServerName hitesh_web.dev
   ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common

   <Directory "C:/Users/Vikas/Documents/NetBeansProjects/slider_website_hitesh/public_html">
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
   </Directory>

   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   ## this is 2nd virtual host

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
   DocumentRoot "E:/dabkick_git/DabKickWebsite"
   ServerName  www.my_mobile.dev
   ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common

   <Directory "E:/dabkick_git/DabKickWebsite">
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. In hosts.ics file of windows os “C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host.ics”

   ```
   127.0.0.1             localhost
   127.0.0.1             hitesh_web.dev
   127.0.0.1             www.my_mobile.dev
   127.0.0.1             demo.multisite.dev
   ```

4.now type your “domain names” in the browser it will ping the particular folder specified in the documentRoot path

5.if you want to access those files in a particular port then replace 80 in httpd-vhosts.conf with port numbers like below and restart apache

```
   <VirtualHost *:4000>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Vikas/Documents/NetBeansProjects/slider_website_hitesh/public_html"
ServerName hitesh_web.dev
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common

<Directory "C:/Users/Vikas/Documents/NetBeansProjects/slider_website_hitesh/public_html">
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

## this is the 2nd vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:7000>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
DocumentRoot "E:/dabkick_git/DabKickWebsite"
ServerName  www.dabkick_mobile.dev
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common

<Directory "E:/dabkick_git/DabKickWebsite">
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: for port number given virtual hosts you have to ping in browser like “http://hitesh_web.dev:4000/” or 
  “http://www.dabkick_mobile.dev:7000/”

6.After doing all those changes you have to save the files and restart apache respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed a module on Xampp (on Linux) via Bitnami and changed `chown` settings, make sure that the `/opt/lampp/apps/<app>/htdocs` and `tmp` usergroup is `daemon` with all other sibling files and folders `chown`ed to the user you installed as, e.g. `cd /opt/lampp/apps/<app>`, `sudo chown -R root:root .`, followed by `sudo chown -R root:daemon htdocs tmp`.