# Access local server(WAMP) on an android device

Tags: android, wamp

I am trying to access WAMP running on my computer (win 8.1) through my android device. I followed the steps given in this [link](http://hack4machine.blogspot.in/2012/05/access-local-pc-server-from-android.html). But when I run I go to the IP address specified, I get "**Forbidden**" error on my phone. It says:
"You don't have permission to acccess / on this server." Any help?

Comment: are you trying to open phpmyadmin?

Comment: Not particularly. I am using laravel with wamp and just want to access my website through a phone.

Comment: have a try on this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495596/i-get-access-forbidden-error-403-when-setting-up-new-alias