# I am not able to access to my XAMPP folder from another PC in same LAN

Tags: php, xampp, firewall, sharing, lan

I am able to access my XAMPP server Dashboard in an another PC in LAN. But I am not able to access any folder other than dashboard.
I have changed my ports 80->87 SSL port 443->444. I have turned off my firewall. Also added Inbound Rules and Outbound Rules to firewall (being safer).

Update - No Access means Error:

> This site can't be reached. www.172.18.5.14's server DNS address could not be found.

But I am able to go for 172.18.5.14/dashboard/

`httpd-ssl.conf` [Link](http://pastebin.ca/3371770)
`httpd-xaamp.conf` [Link](http://pastebin.ca/3371769)
`httpd.conf file` [Link](http://pastebin.ca/3371767)

Comment: Maybe a problem with `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: "Unable to access" means? you are getting any forbidden error? Please be specific to help you better!

Comment: Is apace listening on the right IPs? (for local access, it uses 127.0.0.1, as for LAN, it should use *)

Comment: Check if below URLs might help you out?!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083323/error-when-trying-to-access-xampp-from-a-network
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495596/i-get-access-forbidden-error-403-when-setting-up-new-alias

Comment: got a firewall running?

Comment: This link might help http://serverfault.com/questions/254947/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to

Comment: Please add your configuration files to the question itself - they can be formatted using the 'code' button. Links that are external to Stack Overflow generally break over time, and cause extra editing work. Thanks.