# iframe tag not saving in db

Tags: php, mysql, iframe

While saving embed code `Error 403` coming.

Below is my input data:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></iframe>
```

It is not saved in DB. So I just echo the whole insert query, it coming like below:

> Access forbidden!
>       You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403
>       localhost
>       Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24

Comment: What do you mean from saving embed code? Do you want to save the content of iframe? or the iframe tag code?

Comment: I want to save the entire string `<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></iframe>` in db. `embed_code` is the field name

Comment: Ok. So please add your php code which saves this string.

Comment: Are you using Xampp?

Comment: yes. I am using Xampp

Comment: This error is not from your codes. You have not permission on directory your working on. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495596/i-get-access-forbidden-error-403-when-setting-up-new-alias

Comment: How are you trying to save? Depending on what you are doing, you may be triggering a content filter since iframes can be considered potentially dangerous content that normal users should not be able to save.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same, and there are 2 solutions.-

1 - for some people works to add this code to the .htaccess file:

SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off

2 - in MY case, the issue occurs in the production server because of a security module of Apache (the same before, but the cpanel don't allow the user to mess with that config. So in Namecheap.com servers, thech support enable the feature for us in a pair of minutes, and solved.

I paste here two articles explaining that:

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9542/22/what-is-modsecurity-and-why-do-we-need-it/

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10512/12/how-to-work-with-the-modsecurity-plugin/